# MATLAB - 3D volume fill based on inequalities

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have three variables `x`, `y` and `z`. I have inequalities of the form

`x >= a, y>= b, z>=c, x+y>=d, y+z>=e, x+z>=f, x+y+z>=g`

where `a` to `g` are positive numbers. On a 3D plot with axes `x`, `y` and `z`, this is an open volume. I would like to fill the open side (i.e. away from 0) shape with color and show it in a plot. What is the way to do this on MATLAB?

I attempted to use `fill3` and a mesh but the result was not very good

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(0:0.01:2,0:0.01:2,0:0.01:2);
ineq = (x>=1)& (y>0.5)&(z>=0.25)&(x+y>1.25)&(y+z>0.6)&(x+z>1.1)&(x+y+z>1.6);
fill3(x(:),y(:),z(:), 'r')
box on
grid on
```

Using `plot3` also was not very good. Is there any other way to generate a nice 3D figure on MATLAB?

Mathematica does this using RegionPlot3D. I was hoping for a similar resultant image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be careful when using 3D meshes, the one you defined contains 8M+ points.

Assuming your shape is convex, you can use [convhull](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convhull.html) and [trisurf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html):

Not that the option `'Simplify'` is set as true to reduce the number of elements accounted for in the convex hull.

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(0:0.1:2,0:0.1:2,0:0.1:2);
ineq = (x>=1)& (y>0.5)&(z>=0.25)&(x+y>1.25)&(y+z>0.6)&(x+z>1.1)&(x+y+z>1.6);

figure;

x_ineq = x(ineq);
y_ineq = y(ineq);
z_ineq = z(ineq);

id_cvhl = convhull(x_ineq,y_ineq,z_ineq,'Simplify',true);

trisurf(id_cvhl,x_ineq,y_ineq,z_ineq,'FaceColor','cyan','edgecolor','none')

xlim([0 2])
ylim([0 2])
zlim([0 2])
```

[image]

In case you want the result to look a bit more than RegionPlot3D, don't use `Simplify`, and plot the edges (Be careful not too have a mesh with too many points!).

```
id_cvhl = convhull(x_ineq,y_ineq,z_ineq);

trisurf(id_cvhl,x_ineq,y_ineq,z_ineq,'Facecolor','yellow')
```

[image]